# Prevent JSON.Net custom converter from converting child objects

Tags: json.net

I’m receiving JSON from a service which is a set of search results. Each object in the “results” array could be one of two types of objects (cat/dog I my example). Here’s some example JSON:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Kitty"
    },
    {
      "type": "dog",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Rover",
      "cat": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Missy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I’m deserializing the JSON root object to “SearchResult”. Each item in the "results" is a “SearchResultItem”.

Here’s what my models like for the items:

```
public class Cat : SearchResultItem
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}  
}

public class Dog : SearchResultItem
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public Cat {get; set;}  
}
```

I’ve created a custom converter to convert to the correct type for each object:

```
public class SearchResultConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<SearchResultItem>
    {
        public override SearchResultItem Create(Type objectType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public SearchResultItem Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
        {
            var type = (string)jObject.Property("type");
            switch (type)
            {
                case "cat":
                    return new Cat();
                case "dog":
                    return new Dog();
            }

            return null;

            //throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("The given vehicle type {0} is not supported!", type));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // Load JObject from stream
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

// Create target object based on JObject
            var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

// Populate the object properties
            serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

            return target;
        }
    }
```

The issue I’m having is that Dog happens to have a child item which is a Cat. My converter is catching this Cat object and trying to convert it. Only the results object have a “type” property, any instance of a child Cat or Dog won’t have this “type” property. The absence of this property is causing an Null Reference exception.

How do I restrict the converter to only the top level items in the “results” array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to override [`JsonConverter.CanConvert`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) and have it return true when `typeof(SearchResultItem) == objectType`, rather than when it is *assignable from* `objectType`:

```
public class SearchResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SearchResultItem);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public SearchResultItem Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        // As before
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // As before
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("SearchResultConverter should only be used while deserializing.");
    }
}
```

Now the converter will be called only when attempting to deserialize an instance of `SearchResultItem`.  For members already declared to be of type `Dog` or `Cat` its `ReadJson()` method will not get called.